# Longpress on folder to get pop up menu

Tags: java, android, appium

I have created one folder and now i want to delete that.
I want long press on that folder to get pop up menu and then want to select and delete . How can i do that ?

I did this to get pop up menu but nothing happening

```
WebElement ele =driver.findElement(By.name("XYZ"));
TouchAction action =new TouchAction(((AndroidDriver)driver));
action.longPress(ele, 1000).release().perform();
```

[image]
[image]

In First Image One Folder is there and in second image i got one menu when pressed and hold folder.
How can i automate this ?

Comment: need more explanation

Comment: Does your long press not working for 1000 ms?
Or you are not able to select the 'Delete' option?

Comment: Long press not at all working .

Comment: Can you try by increasing the ms from 1000 to 3000 or 4000

Comment: Already Tried ....did not worked

Comment: try `action.longPress(ele, 3000).perform();`

Answer (score 0):

The way of accessing the element was not correct, 
Try this and let me know:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='XYZ']"));
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(((AndroidDriver)driver));
action.longPress(ele, 4000).perform();
```

[image]

Comment: How are you finding the locator for folder 'XYZ', Are you using UIAutomator Viewer, can you share the screenshot after capturing it in UI Automator Viewer

Comment: Have A Look On Attached Screen Shot

Comment: @RajAbhishek: I had updated my answer, please try and check, i hope it should work now

Comment: Still Same, unable to get pop up menu. How it will make difference by using xpath ? Since i am getting locator elements in UIAutomatorviewer , Is this feature supported by Appium ?